# Set background layout programmatically from image downloaded with volley

Tags: android, background-image, android-volley

I have a relative layout where I would like to set the background image from an image downloaded with volley, is it possible? How could I do that?

Edit: So here is the layout where I would like to load the image in background:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/bg_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:background="@drawable/detail_background" // HERE
    tools:context="com.kalianey.oxapp.views.fragments.ProfileFragment">
```

Usually I load images in ImageView via volley like this :

```
imageView.setImageUrl(user.getCover_url(), imageLoader);
```

But I don't see how to do it via drawable...

Comment: Show some code. What have you tried?

Comment: @iturki Sorry, I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no more information given.
It is possible, and depending on what format your image is it can be simple.  It can just be relativelayout.setBackground(Drawable) if its already a drawable if not, then you can convert to one. And that should be one potential answer.

Comment: I edited my question to be more precise, could you tell me how to convert download the image and convert it in a drawable to set it?

Comment: Oh if you already can get the image like that then do that, then  after you use `imageView.setImageUrl(user.getCover_url(), imageLoader);`  do something like this `relativeLayout.setBackground(imageview.getDrawable)`.  This should work I believe.

Comment: But in this case I don't have an imageview as I want to set the background image of the relative layout, so do I need to create an imageview and hide it or something?

Comment: Ah well you don't even have to apply it just create one programtically,  something like ImageView imageview = new Imageview(this);

Comment: Thanks as well and no problem!